# How to print data array using php json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I want to print data like this using php **json_encode**
so what the php code to output this data for using java script code .

```
var data = [{
"name": "test",
    "calories": "1000",
    "fat": "100",
    "protein": "100",
    "carbohydrates": "800",
 }, {
"name": "test2",
    "calories": "10000",
    "fat": "343",
    "protein": "3434",
    "carbohydrates": "4343",
 }];
```

I am try this php code but the data output not like i want.

```
<?PHP
 $RESULT = array();

 for($x=0;$x<=4;$x++){
   $RESULT["data"]["name"][]    = "Name" . $x;
   $RESULT["data"]["calories"][]    = "calories" . $x;
   $RESULT["data"]["fat"][]    = "fat" . $x;
   $RESULT["data"]["protein"][]    = "protein" . $x;
   $RESULT["data"]["carbohydrates"][]    = "carbohydrates" . $x;
 }

 echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($RESULT).");";
?>
```

I want json_encode print the data like first code .

Comment: Did you try `json_encode($RESULT, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)` to pretty print? Whats the problem?

Comment: You just solved your problem `json_encode`

Comment: Do `print_r($RESULT)` and you'll see what you have...  You have multiple things wrong here

Comment: The problems was in ["data"] .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you plan to use it or what you're doing with `$_GET['callback']`, but the main issue is that you need to append elements under a new array under `data`:

```
for($x=0;$x<=4;$x++){
    $RESULT["data"][$x]["name"] = "Name" . $x;
    $RESULT["data"][$x]["calories"] = "calories" . $x;
    $RESULT["data"][$x]["fat"] = "fat" . $x;
    $RESULT["data"][$x]["protein"] = "protein" . $x;
    $RESULT["data"][$x]["carbohydrates"] = "carbohydrates" . $x;
}
echo json_encode($RESULT, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

So:

```
$RESULT["data"][$x]["name"]
```

Not:

```
$RESULT["data"]["name"][]
```

Comment: Thanks i change to $RESULT[$x]["name"]  and is working .